# Hash Delete Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash, pseudocode

I am reading the book, Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition, and in the section involving Hash Insert and Search, there is a mention to the Hash Delete algorithm, but no actual code for it. It states that you cannot delete a key from slot i because then it might be possible to not be able to retrieve a key. So instead, the special value of Key Deleted is applied to the slot. Then, the algorithm for Hash Insert would treat the slot as empty and and insert the key there. So, I took upon myself to rewrite the Hash Insert algorithm for the Hash Delete, and I wanted to know if my Hash Delete algorithm works to mark the delete.
T is defined as the hash table, and k is defined as the key.
Hash Insert(T, k)         (This is from the book)
i = 0 
repeat
j = h(k, i)
if T[j] == nil
T[j] = k
return j
else i = i + 1
until i == m
error "hash table overflow"

Now this is my Hash delete algorithm
Hash Delete (T, k) 
i = 0
repeat
if T[j] == NIL
i = i++
if i == m 
error "hash table overflow"
return j
else if T[j] == k
k = "Deleted"

Does this pseudo code work for hash delete? Should I move the else if statement further up, or is it fine where it is? Should I keep the hash table overflow in case the value is not found within the array? My thought process is that I should in case that specific key is not found within array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your question to point that this is about **open-addressing hashing scheme**. This issue would not occur in chained hashing.

You don't need to modify `HASH-SEARCH` algorithm. It will just pass over `DELETED` as if it were some other value. Here is the modified `HASH-DELETE` algorithm based on the new convention:

```
r <- HASH-SEARCH(key)

if r == NIL

    return NIL

else
    
    T[r] = DELETED
    
    return T[r]
```

Based on the above, you you can modify `HASH-INSERT` as follows:

```
i <- 0

repeat j <- h(k,i)

    if T[j] == NIL or T[j] == DELETED
         
        then T[j] <- k
           
            return j

        else i <- i + 1

until i == m

error "hash table overflow"
```

`HASH-INSERT` will treat `DELETED` as empty and use it, but `HASH-SEARCH` and `HASH-INSERT` will just treat it as some random non-target value and pass.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!